# How can I install pantheon terminal in (L)ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: lubuntu, pantheon

I tried to install `pantheon-terminal` from `elementaryos/daily` PPA as instructed in a question about how to install it in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ... but it did not work. When I run `sudo apt install pantheon-terminal` I receive the message `E: Unable to locate package pantheon-terminal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `pantheon-terminal` package available for Ubuntu 16.10 in the elementary daily PPA and that is the reason why no installation candidate is offered to install on Ubuntu edition 16.10.

Installation candidates (packages) are available for Ubuntu editions 14.04 / 16.04 / 17.04 only ->

[image]

Reference : [elementary OS team | elementary Daily](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily/) (you'll find `pantheon-terminal` on page 3)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to install it manually?

Comment: @RjQuery Better don't try - it wouldn't be a good idea, because it might break something in the system. :)